# How to customise header section in static cell?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

I want to customise the header section in my application but it's in static cell. I tried to make one cell to be my header by including identifier and add a new file to control that cell but that doesn't work. I tried to drag an object into new file but it's can't be done. So how to customise section header? Is my way of approach is good?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific please? Do you mean in a table view? If you have sections in your table, they can be seen in the document outline (the one that lists all the controllers and their objects). If you click on a section, in the attributes inspector there is a field for setting the header of that section.

Comment: Yes in table view controller. I want to insert an image into header. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to customize the header section in a `UITableView`. For instance, if all you want to do is change the text, you can do so in the **attributes inspector** while making sure your **TableViewSection** is selected:

[image]

[image]

However, if you want the ability to do customizations such as text size, tont, capitalizations - any customizations inherent to UILabels, you'll need to override this method from the `UITableViewController`:

```
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    let header = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    header.textLabel.textColor = UIColor(red: 243/255, green: 153/255, blue: 193/255, alpha: 1.0)
    header.textLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 18)
    header.textLabel.text = "About Us"
    header.textLabel.frame = header.frame
    header.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
  }
```

For example, in the code above, I took the header that was passed as a parameter and configured the textColor, font, text, alignment - really anything you can do on the UILabel can be done here.

**Before customization**

[image]

**After customization**

[image]

Comment: I tried you code. It doesn't work nothing happen. @Kelvin Lau

Comment: Definitely works for me. Did you make sure you're using your `UITableViewController` subclass?

Comment: @asiandudeCom Added before and after screenshots of the simulator.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can customise header section use Nib. Simple example below.

[HeaderView.xib (Screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1Ur3.png)

HeaderView.swift

```
import UIKit

class HeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleBackgroundView: UIView!

     static var nib: UINib {
       return UINib(nibName: identifier, bundle: nil)
     }

     static var identifier: String {
       return String(describing: self)
     }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
      titleBackgroundView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
      titleBackgroundView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
      titleBackgroundView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 5)
      titleBackgroundView.layer.shadowRadius = 5
    }
}
```

ProfileTableViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ProfileTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(HeaderView.nib, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: HeaderView.identifier)
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

      let headerView = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: HeaderView.identifier) as! HeaderView
        switch section {
        case 0:
          headerView.titleLabel.text = "Profile"
          return headerView
        case 1:
          headerView.titleLabel.text = "Social"
          return headerView
        default:
          return UIView()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }
}
```

[Simulator (Screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sH8Ky.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is the easy way to do it without set a new string, just leave text in header that used in UITableview with static cell as it and add this override for header in your code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewHeaderFooterView class]]) {
        ((UITableViewHeaderFooterView*)view).textLabel.text = [((UITableViewHeaderFooterView*)view).textLabel.text capitalizedString];
    }
}
```